# Is there idiomatic opposite of Result<T, Infallible>?

Tags: rust

When one wants to show that trait returning `Result` should never fail the `Infallible` is used as an error type like in example below:

```
trait Foo {
    type T;
    type E: std::error::Error;
    fn bar() -> Result<Self::T, Self::E>;
}

impl Foo for () {
    type T = ();
    type E = std::convert::Infallible;
    fn bar() -> Result<Self::T, Self::E> { Ok(()) }
}
```

But what should one do with implementation that will always return `Err` and never `Ok`? Is there idiomatic way to fill the blank below:

```
impl Foo for MyCustomError {
    type T = //what to put here as "never returned type";
    type E = MyCustomError;
    fn bar() -> Result<Self::T, Self::E> { Err(MyCustomError) }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the never type?

Comment: @Mafii indeeed, compiled in nightly with `never` this works nice. Is there any counterpart in stable version of rust?

Comment: you can use the [Infallible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html) type, but it has some differences https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fmllgx/never_crate_stable_alternative_to/

Comment: You can put there a never, a unit or a zero-sized enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once never stabilizes you can just use that.

```rust
#![feature(never)]
impl Foo for MyCustomError {
    type T = !;
    type E = MyCustomError;
    fn bar() -> Result<Self::T, Self::E> { Err(MyCustomError) }
}
```

Until then we can construct our own empty enum:

```rust
enum Void {}
impl Foo for MyCustomError {
    type T = Void;
    type E = MyCustomError;
    fn bar() -> Result<Self::T, Self::E> { Err(MyCustomError) }
}
```

which can't be constructed for obvious reasons, Rust also sees that and optimizes accordingly.
Or use [`void::Void`](https://docs.rs/void/latest/void/enum.Void.html) or `Infallible` which except for the different traits each implements are essentially the same.